# What is JSON.NET for? MVC already has a way to convert objects to json

Tags: javascript, serialization, json.net

I looked at the JSON.NET site but I am not getting it... I already have code like this ..

```
  string[] invalidFiles = new string[] { "one.xls", "two.xls", "three.xls" };

        return Json(new
        {
            Status = "OK",
            InvalidFiles = invalidFiles
        });
```

that turns objects into json... So I looked at JSON.NET and that seems to do the same thing ? What am I missing ? What isa  simple example of what JSON.NET can do that I can do with

```
protected internal JsonResult Json(object data);
```

??

Comment: It depends on what version of MVC you are using, Microsoft incorporated the JSON.net library into the newer versions of MVC because it was that useful...

Comment: I am using MVC 4.. so does that mean I am using it when I call that 'Json' method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Web API in MVC 4 the default serializer is the json.net library, however when returning a JsonResult in MVC 4 from standard controllers the default serializer used is [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). You can create a custom jsonresult and override the Json method in standard controllers to use the Json.Net library by default.

To use json.net you can first create a custom result:

```
   public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
   {
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Controller Context");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }

        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data);

        response.ContentType = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType)
            ? ContentType
            : "application/json";
        response.Write(jsonData);
    }
}
```

Then override the json method in a base controller method and return json like your currently doing:

```
    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult() {
            Data = data,
            ContentType = contentType,
            ContentEncoding = contentEncoding
        };
    }
```